# The Model-to-View communication in MVC?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm learning MVC now and I just got that when the model is modified by the controller, it can notify the view to update the data from model. While I'm quite confused about it. Since the model is modified by the controller rather than itself or something else, it should be the controller that sends the update notification to the view. Also I haven't found any example of such Model-to-View communication, please give me one to make it clear if anyone understands this idea well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model to view communication is often accomplished via the Observer pattern. The code in views tends to change more than the code in models, so Model-View separation means the model elements don't depend directly on the view elements. You can add or change view code and the model code is not affected.

A model element whose state changes just notifies all its observers. The state change can happen because of a controller, or because of other reasons (values change over time).

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx in particular the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC100217.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The central component of MVC, the `model`, captures the behavior of the application in terms of its problem domain, independent of the user interface. The `model` directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application. A `view` can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram.
The third part, the `controller`, accepts input and converts it to commands for the `model` or `view`.

Typically the `controller` receives user input such as key presses and mouse clicks and based on that modifies the `model`. When the `model` changes the `view` needs to be updated to reflect the changes.

There are a couple of options how to implement the `view` updating.

A) The `view` update can be implemented by calling it directly from the `controller` after it has modified the `model`. For an example, see [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/model-view-controller/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/model/view/controller).

B) The `view` update can be implemented using the [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. In this case the `model` fires update events on the `view` each time there is a relevant change in the `model`. For an example see [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/model-view-controller/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/model/view/controller/with/observer).

Comment: Why do we need the second way? I think It's the controller that changes the model, it can notify the view by the way.

Comment: I removed the second option to keep it simple. Thanks for the comment @Ivan814

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, the second option is what I'm focusing on in this question.

Comment: Ok, unedited the answer :) So to clarify are you looking for an example of B?

Comment: **So to clarify are you looking for an example of B?** Yes

Comment: I have added links to examples of both A and B.

Comment: Well, your examples just show me how to implement the second option, but don't  illustrate me that why we need it. Anyway, I have got it in the other answer.